# Problem: First determine whether Polyhedron is pointed. If it is find all extreme points of the Polyhedron.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

The Polyhedron is defined by these inequalities

$x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 \ge 1$

$−x_2 \ge 0$

$x_2 + x_3 \ge 0$

$−x_1 + x_3 \ge −2$

First I want to say you can use the rank condition to determine weather it is pointed or not. A non-empty polyhedron is said to be "pointed" if it does not contain a "line" (An infinite line that extends infinitely in both directions).  I'm trying to do this without drawing a sketch. It's easy when only working in a two dimensional space but here we are working in three. Not exactly sure how we would apply it.

I tried this instead, take combinations of all the subsystems(inequalities) make them (equality)  If anything has multiple solutions it will not contain an extreme point. Start with combination of one, then combination of two, I'm not sure a combination of two would actually help. When I did a combination of three ex. $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = 1$  ... $−x_2 = 0$ ... $x_2 + x_3 = 0$ by solving you get a unique solution (1, 0, 0) so this should be an extreme point I believe. Am I going about this correctly? I was informed that I would have to do variable elimination but i'm really not sure. Any advice or help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question could use some improvements. First, use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematical formulas, they are somewhat hard to read. Second, define your terms: What does it mean for a polyhedron to be "pointed"? What is the "rank condition"? Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) under the heading "Provide Definitions".